# Server Side Rendering and generating cached index.html ( Vuejs, Nodejs)

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js

Multiple web sites (site1.com, site2.com) are connected to one server. I can catch domain name when user enter a site. Using this domain name i fetch suitable json from api and display items. Each site has different logo, background colors, items and etc. Each time I use axios to fetch data from api.

At the end, I have 3 problems.

1. Website should work if there is something wrong with api.
2. Google should index the websites separately
3. getting data by Axios is happened each time ( refreshing page)

To solve these 3 problems, I decided using SSR. Using Node.js or Express.js i can get all of domains list from api and get all data of websites separately. Then I can generate cached index.html. It will be rendered, per 30 minutes. At the end in frontend (Vue.js), instead of calling Axios, we can use cached index.html. I think that it could also help indexing web site for SEO.

My question:

- Is my solution a sensible approach?
- How can I make a cached.html?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think your solution posses more than a simple answer, but at least in SSR Nuxt.js is the way to go when using Vue.js. You can dive in the documentation here:

[See: Server Rendered](https://nuxtjs.org/guide#server-rendered-universal-ssr-)

Comment: installing nuxt,js to Vue should be at the beginning of level. It is working website, it will be very complicated installing Nuxt. Also, this is a situation we should find correct way. Reading a documentation is not a solution.

Comment: I agree with you, but it's hard to give an answer too, especially to a complex problem. And also you can add next to an existing project, you just need to have a developing environment and a staging environment, in order to deploy properly in the future.